# MacOS app: how do I access the user's documents folder?

Tags: swift, macos

I am developing a Mac OS SwiftUI application and I would like to access the user's documents folder.

I tried this:

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
```

But instead of getting:

> file:///Users/me/Documents

I'm getting:

> file:///Users/me/Library/Containers/com.me.MyApp/Data/Documents/

How to do so?

Thank you for your help

Comment: That's the expected directory if the application is sandboxed